# How do I delete all rows with a blank space in the third column within a file?

Tags: bash, shell

So, I have a file which contains the results of some calculations I've run in the past weeks. I've collected the results in a file which I intend to plot. It is basically a bunch of rows with the format "x" "y" "f(x,y)", like this:

```
1.7 4.7 -460.5338556921
1.7 4.9 -460.5368762353
1.7 5.5
```

However, some lines, exemplified by the last one, contain a blank space in the 3rd column, resulting from failed calculations. I'd still like to plot the viable points, but, as there are thousands of points (and therefore rows) that task just be accomplished easily by hand. I'd like to know how to make a script or program (I'd prefer a shell script, but I'll gladly go along with whatever works), which identifies those lines and deletes them. Does anyone know a way to do it?

Comment: `awk 'NF==3' file`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '$3' <filename>
```

or better

```
awk 'NF > 2' <filename> # if in any entry in the column-3 happens to be zero
```

This will do the purpose!

Comment: This is very likely equivalent to `awk filename`, which is a perfectly valid awk program that will read stdin and evaluate the variable `filename` to 0 for each line of input, correctly doing nothing.

Comment: I missed the single quotes, I hope this is fine now @william

Comment: Once fixed with quotes, this is a good simple approach.  But it will skip any line in which the data point happens to be zero!  It's probably better to use `NF > 2`

Comment: Thanks for this @willium . Stackoverflow is amazing to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form of grep command that should probably be understood by any shell these days:

```
grep -v '^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*$' <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

With grep:

```
grep ' .* [^ ]' file
```

or using ERE:

```
grep -E '\s\S+\s\S' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would to use:

```
perl -lanE 'print if @F==3 && /^[\d\s\.+-]+$/' file
```

will print only lines:

- which contains 3 fields
- *and* contains only numbers, spaces, and `.+-`

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you are going to plot. You would like a `grep` or `awk` solution and pipe all valid lines into your plotting application.
When you need to call a program for each set of values, you can skip the invalid lines when you are reading the values:

```
while read -r x y fxy; do
   if [ -n "${fxy}" ]; then
      myplotter "$x" "$y" "${fxy}"
   fi
done < file
```